# Example of a ring for which $rs \neq 0$ but $sr = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, noncommutative-algebra

I am looking for an example of an associative noncommutative ring $R$ with the following property: for $r,s \in R$,
$$
rs \neq 0, \text{  but  } sr = 0.
$$
Moreover, do rings for which this cannot happen have a name?

Comment: This is the case where $r$ is a _right zero-divisor_ but not a _left zero-divisor_ and, conversely,  $s$ is a _left zero-divisor_ but not a _right zero-divisor_ (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183504493).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices, say with real entries, look at 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general remarks.

First, some model theory. The claim that $(R, r, s)$ is a tuple consisting of a ring $R$ and two elements $r, s \in R$ such that $rs \neq 0$ but $sr = 0$ can be formalized in first-order logic. The [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem#Model_existence_theorem) then guarantees that such a statement has a model (namely, a ring exists with these properties) if and only if it is consistent (namely, one cannot give a first-order proof of a contradiction from it).

Next, some category theory. There is a universal tuple $(R, r, s)$ of a ring $R$ and two elements $r, s \in R$ such that $sr = 0$: it is the quotient of the free ring $\mathbb{Z} \langle r, s \rangle$ on two generators $r, s$ by the relation $sr = 0$. Any example must be a quotient of this ring, and hence examples exist iff $rs \neq 0$ in this particular ring. It's possible to show that the underlying abelian group of this ring is free abelian on elements of the form $r^n s^m$, which proves this result and various other stronger results too.